# Exception when receiving a GCM notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I was previously using version 4.9.2 of the marketing cloud SDK on Android to recieve notificaitons and it all worked fine. However after updating to 5.0.4 I get the following exception in the log when a notifcation is receved from GCM:

`E/~!PushMessageManager: Unable to show GCM notification
Sdk Version: 5.0.4
 Google Play Services Version: 10240000
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing required properties: id
     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.$$AutoValue_NotificationMessage$a.c(Unknown Source)
     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationMessage$a.d(Unknown Source)
     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationMessage.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.PushMessageManager.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.PushMessageManager.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.PushMessageManager$a.onReceive(Unknown Source)
     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)`

I know I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere, but I'm struggling to find where the required "id" propertly I'm missing would be.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending the push notification: via the Marketing Cloud or via some other method?

Comment: That was from our own server communicating with GCM. However I have tried sending a push notification as mentioned in step 7 of the help guide (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html) and this error also occurs.

Comment: Hi Bill, has there been any update on this yet? Thanks.

Comment: I got this issue and solved, you can find in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222098/missing-required-properties-id-alert/222148#222148).

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the id field `_m` in the payload.

Please see troubleshooting docs: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Answer (score -1):

We ran into this issue as well.  The solution (for us) was to use the Legacy Server Key from the Firebase Console (not the regular server key).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks for the tip, I'll give this a test soon!

Comment: Unfortunately I must have already been using the legacy key, as the same issue occurs.

Comment: The error message, `Missing required properties: id` means you did not include a message id in your payload.