# Missing required properties: id alert

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have some thing trouble in the [LearningAPPAndroid](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid). I just clone this project and change the **secrets.xml** with my MarketingCloud **ID, AccessToken** and firebase sender_ID. But when i run this project and use [pushWatch](https://www.pushwatch.com/gcm/) to send a message. when my phone get the message(no push notification) I catch an error in logcat.

```
E/~!a: Unable to show GCM notification
   Sdk Version: 5.5.1
   Google Play Services Version: 11910000
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing required properties: id alert
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.$$AutoValue_NotificationMessage$a.c(Unknown Source)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationMessage$a.d(Unknown Source)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationMessage.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.a.c(Unknown Source)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.a.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.a$a.onReceive(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:311)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:47)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:120)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

I find [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179880/exception-when-receiving-a-gcm-notification) and try that way but it still not worked.

I am so confused. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: With Bill's Answer. I just change the json which is get from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

before

```json
{       
  "registration_ids":["your token key"],
  "data": {
      "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
     }
}
```

after

```json
{       
  "registration_ids":["your token key"],
  "data": {
      "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
      "_m": "1",
      "alert": "this is alert"
     }
}
```

And that works~

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the id field `_m` and the message to be shown `alert` in the payload.

Please see troubleshooting docs: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Comment: Thank you, I just add some field in my request Json. And it works.